# Modify the signature of all functions in a class with a high order function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with writing a library in Typescript and let's say I'm given the following class:

```
class SomeService {
  fn1(commonParam: string, a: number, b: string): string {
  }

  fn2(commonParam: string, c: Date): string {
  }
}
```

Is it possible to write a high order function in Typescript that if called like:

`const ResultService = transform(SomeService);`

Would result in a const with the the following type:

```
const ResultService: class {
  fn1(a: number, b: string): void {
  }

  fn2(c: Date): void {
  }
}
```

So basically it would result in the `const` would be the class with the same functions but with the commonParam removed and a different return type.
The idea is to wrap this class and have these params passed by the engine of the library.

Another option, if simpler, would be to write the class as:

```
class SomeService {
  fn1 = (commonParam: string) => (a: number, b: string): string => {
  }

  fn2 = (commonParam: string) => (c: Date): string => {
  }
}
```

or:

```
class SomeService {
  fn1 = (a: number, b: string) => (commonParam: string): string => {
  }

  fn2 = (c: Date) => (commonParam: string): string => {
  }
}
```

And have the higher order function converting the functions in the class to a version without the `(commonParam: string)` like the example from earlier.

I've been trying to find a solution for this on Google but I couldn't so far, I'm starting to think it's not possible, but I'm just giving a try here as a last attempt.

Doing this transformation in Javascript is easy, but I want it to be strongly typed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of mapped types, conditional types, and rest tuple expansion:

```
type RemoveCommonParam<T extends {}> = {
  [TKey in keyof T]:
      T[TKey] extends (commonParam: string, ...args: infer TArgs) => unknown
      ? (...args: TArgs) => void
      : T[TKey]; 
}
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20SomeService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fn1(commonParam%3A%20string%2C%20a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20fn2(commonParam%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20Date)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20fn3(commonParam%3A%20string%2C%20a%3A%20boolean%2C%20b%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RemoveCommonParam%3CT%20extends%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTKey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20T%5BTKey%5D%20extends%20(commonParam%3A%20string%2C%20...args%3A%20infer%20TArgs)%20%3D%3E%20unknown%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20(...args%3A%20TArgs)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%5BTKey%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ResultService%20%3D%20RemoveCommonParam%3CSomeService%3E%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20x%3A%20ResultService%3B)

Comment: Wow, that works pretty well! Thanks.
I'm just wondering if it would be possible to keep the argument names in the functions. Even if I use one of the other options from my examples.

Comment: I doubt that is possible.